# Importing multi-Relational Data with magicalpanda's MagicalRecord

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I would like to import a json-file into my SQLite-CoreData-Database with the help of magical panda's MagicalRecord. 
This is the Content of my json-file:

```
{
 "title":"Gebratener Schweinebauch auf dänische Art",
 "subtitle":"Stegt flaesk med persillesauce",
 "preparation_time":"35 Min.",
 "preparation_subtitle":"bei 225°C, nicht vorheizen.",
 "components":[
  {
        "name":"Hauptgericht",
                "ingredients": [
       {
          "name":"1 kg geschälte und gekochte Kartoffeln"
       }
  ]
  }
 ]
}
```

i am trying to import the content of the file into the following core-data-model: 
Image of the Data model: http://twitpic.com/8fa0y9

i use the following code to import the json-file:

```
- (void)initializeRecipeDatabase {
NSString *resource = [[NSBundle mainBundle]     pathForResource:kRecipeInitialDatabaseContentFilename 
                                                                                                         ofType:kRecipeInitialDatabaseContentFileType];
NSError *parsingError = nil;
NSDictionary *result = nil;

if (NSClassFromString(@"NSJSONSerialization")) {
    NSInputStream *inputStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath:resource];
    [inputStream open];

    result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithStream:inputStream options:0 error:&parsingError];
}
else {
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:resource];
    result = [jsonData objectFromJSONData];
}

[Recipe MR_truncateAll];
[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_save];
[Recipe MR_importFromDictionary:result];
[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_save];


}
```

The import works without giving me an error, but when i inspect the content of the SQLite-Database, i have two equal entries in the Ingredient-Table:

Image of the Database-Content: http://twitpic.com/8fa0k3

Currently i am kind of helpless, to solve this problem, and i would be very happy, if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You've found a bug in the import process. There is a [pull request](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/pull/137) currently pending that resolves this issue. I've got a backlog of pull requests pending, but you can take a look there and see if that will help you for now.

Comment: I have tried the changes to made with the commit #8c0a084, but this seems not to fix my problem.
I still get those two entries for the Ingredient-Entity :(

Comment: I've seen you have merged the commit #8c0a084 into master - i have pulled the latest version and tested it again, the error with the duplicate Ingredient-Entry still exists.

Comment: I have found a resolution for this problem by myself, you have to define the name of the primary-key-attribute (which should identify your entity unique) in the User Info-Section of your Relationship-Attribute.

Comment: Hi Sascha, I've the same needs that yours..
I need to import data from a webservice that I've created and save them into a core data database.. I've just found the MagicRecord library.. Could you, if you have time, tell me or show me the code you used for inserting the data using several relationships? (I failed to understand how the relationship should work with core data)?
Thanks...